# How to process XML and plain text in single file using boomi?

Tags: etl

In a file i have both plain data as well as XML data how to process in boomi data is like below

80  1   2           ABC 11122233                                                                    A=25    B=94.45 C=81    I=560   Z=2-Gold                                                                                        data`MA02`Best address is different than inputdata`MP03`Best phone is different than inputdata`LP13`Two or more different phones founddata`AA14`Street Addressdata`AP04`Phone is cellular or mobiledata`LA13`Two or more different addresses founddata`VS05`Social reported only with different address(es)data`AS08`Social has been reported560ebureau-score-collection-2018020917520-99920290527data136B8063F-0629-4191-9482-DC5B3AFCD9CF0.28702615026.ABC15026.ABCR4202011122233SMITH, JOHN D888 SE 30TH AVE HILLSBURYID99999xxxxx8888199907555222121220230527-234<origbalance_value>375.91</origbalance_value>9/1/2023 8:09

tried split by line and profile in data process no use